# How to join processes in Promela?

Tags: multithreading, spin, promela

I'm making a model with Promela and I need to wait 2 processes to end in order to continue. How can I achieve that with Promela?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First: theory recap.**

In Promela, a process **ends when** it reaches the end of its code, i.e.

```cpp
active proctype example() 
{
    /* some code */

    /* here it ends */
}
```

When a process **ends**, it is ready for being **terminated** by the system. Being terminated means the following things:

- the `_pid` used by the process is freed and can now be re-used by any other *new* process being instantiated later on.
- any resource used by the process is freed and released

However, notice that there exist some **constraints** on processes termination:

- a process `p_i` is terminated only when it is in its end state and there exists no other process `p_j` whose `_pid` value is larger than that of `p_i` and that it is still alive.

In other words, processes can only be terminated in reverse order of their creation, as indicated in the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/_pid.html).

This limitation is important because in `Spin` there can be only up to `255` processes that are concurrently alive at any given moment. Any attempt to spawn a larger amount of processes with `run` will block, unless some of the existing processes have been correctly terminated in the meanwhile to make room for new processes.

---

**Second: join.**

Now, to implement the `join` operation, we first have to decide what it means for us to do that:

1. the `join` should catch when another process reaches a certain `end state` in its execution
2. the `join` should catch when another process is effectively terminated and its resources are freed by the system

---

**Impl: case 1)**

The first situation is definitively easy to design and implement. We merely need some *synchronization* mechanism among processes so as to notify that the given `end state` has been reached.

This can be done in several ways, depending on the kind of behavioural flavour you want to model. Here is a possible implementation:

```cpp
mtype = { END };

proctype do_something(chan out)
{
    printf("proc[%d]: doing something ...\n", _pid);

end:
    out!_pid, END;
}

init {
    chan in = [5] of { mtype };
    pid pids[5];
    byte idx;

    /* atomic{} is optional here */
    atomic {
        for (idx: 0 .. 4) {
            pids[idx] = run do_something(in);
        }

        printf("init: initialized all processes ...\n");
    }

    /* join section */

    for (idx: 0 .. 4) {
        in??eval(pids[idx]), END;

        printf("init: joined process %d ... \n", pids[idx]);
    }
}
```

---

**Impl: case 2)**

The second situation is a bit more complicated to model and, *to the extent of my knowledge*, it might have some limitations and not being entirely feasible under certain designs.

This approach relies on the value of the variable [`_nr_pr`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/_nr_pr.html), which is a predefined, global, read-only variable recording the number of processes that are currently running.

One can either:

**A.** join one by one all processes we have spawned in reverse order of creation

```cpp
proctype do_something()
{
    printf("proc[%d]: doing something ...\n", _pid);

end:
    /* nothing to do */
}

init {
    pid pids[5];
    byte idx;

    /* atomic{} is optional here */
    atomic {
        for (idx: 0 .. 4) {
            pids[idx] = run do_something();
        }

        printf("init: initialized all processes ...\n");
    }

    /* join section */

    for (idx: 0 .. 4) {
        (_nr_pr <= pids[4 - idx]);

        printf("init: joined process %d ... \n", pids[4 - idx]);
    }
}
```

**B.** join all processes we have spawned at once

```cpp
proctype do_something()
{
    printf("proc[%d]: doing something ...\n", _pid);

end:
    /* nothing to do */
}

init {
    pid pids[5];
    byte idx;

    /* atomic{} is optional here */
    atomic {
        for (idx: 0 .. 4) {
            pids[idx] = run do_something();
        }

        printf("init: initialized all processes ...\n");
    }

    /* join section */

    (_nr_pr <= pids[0]);

    printf("init: all children terminated ... \n");
}
```